# Batch job remove timestamp in a filename with date and time stamp

Tags: batch-file, timestamp, filenames

In a folder, I had many file names such as:

```
ABC.DEF.GHI.YYYYMMDDhhmmss
JKL.MNO.PQR.YYYYMMDDhhmmsss
```

(not sure why sometimes the timestamp had 9 digits, based on the 24 hours)

The desired result is to truncate the timestamp, keep the filename with `YYYMMDD` only:

```
ABC.DEF.GHI.YYYYMMDD 
JKL.MNO.PQR.YYYYMMDD
```

How can I do this in a script batch file, windows (not Linux)?
I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: I'll be honest here, I do not believe you! I can see absolutely no reason why anybody would create or use files where every extension is completely different and in two possible formats, i.e. `.YYYYMMDDhhmmss`, or `.YYYYMMDDhhmmsss`. Please provide the proper actual filenames, and file structure. Whilst you're [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63308625/edit) to do that, please also include the batch-file code, you'd like us to assist you with. Taking account that you should have read the content of [ask] by now, you should know that your question is currently off topic.

Comment: You can seperate the token preceeding the extension using a nested for loop with modifiers to assign the Date/time value to a variable, then trim the resulting value using substring modification. Doing so will require delayed expansion to be enabled.

Comment: @Compo, I understand why you do not believe that I had two different time format but that is exactly what I got.
The files were created by vendor software, not by me.  
The file name in my question are exactly what I had.  
From the application, the users submitted a request that generate the files. 
These files are text files however there are no extension.  The correct file names generated look like these: 
<br>ABC.DEF.GHI.20200908123945<br/> 
<br>JKL.MNO.PQR.20200827230<br/>

and The desire results are  
<br>ABC.DEF.GHI.20200908  
<br>JKL.MNO.PQR.20200827

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly more complete version which assumes that your target files actually have an extension which you omitted to tell us in your question. *(I've used `.csv` for demonstration purposes, just change it as needed)*.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Dir /B /A:-D "<.<.<.>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.csv"') Do (
    For %%H In ("%%~nG") Do (
        Set "DateStamp=%%~xH"
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Ren "%%G" "%%~nH!DateStamp:~,9!%%~xG"
        EndLocal
    )
)
```

**[EDIT /]**

Based upon your clarification, that your files were not assigned extensions by their creation software, your code can be simplified:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Dir /B /A:-D "<.<.<.>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"') Do (
    Set "DateStamp=%%~xG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Ren "%%G" "%%~nG!DateStamp:~,9!"
    EndLocal
)
```

Comment: Hi Compo, thank you very much for your help. I will try and will let you know if it works.

Comment: Hi Compo, I have tried however it did not work.  I modified your script removing .csv as follows:  <br/>   @Echo Off  <br/>
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion  <br/>
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Dir /B /A:-D "<.<.<.>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.csv"') Do (  <br/>
    For %%H In ("%%~nG") Do (  <br/>
        Set "DateStamp=%%~xH"  <br/>
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion  <br/>
        Ren "%%G" "%%~nH!DateStamp:~,9!%%~xG"  <br/>
        EndLocal  <br/>
    )  <br/>
)  <br/>

Comment: @Tubi, I have added an edit to my answer above, to incorporate a modified solution to cater for your filenames not having been assigned extensions. Please note however, that there's now a chance that your filenames may have duplicates, and in those cases, the rename will not work.

Comment: it worked.  thank you so very much.  I also raised another question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63815654/get-newest-file-among-many-then-rename-the-newest-file-name-keeping-first-33-cha) but since this already worked, I will close it and mentioned your name there.  Many thanks again.

Comment: Now I need to add the path in front of the file name. For example I did 'Dir /B /A:-D "D:\Test\<.<.<.>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" instead of 'Dir /B /A:-D "<.<.<.>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" However it did not work, would you know why not? –

Comment: Yes I do, but please note, that your initial question was an off topic code request, and you're now asking for a further change to my code, more than one month later. Please try to fix your own coding issues, my answer above does not tie me into a future support deal. Use the code in my edit, _(but with your change from `"<.<.<.>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"` to `"D:\Test\<.<.<.>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"`)_, but also change `Ren "%%G" "%%~nG!DateStamp:~,9!"` to `Ren "D:\Test\%%G" "%%~nG!DateStamp:~,9!"`. My Preference however would to be leave the code exactly as is, but insert `CD /D "D:\Test"` as a new line `3`.

Comment: To Compo:  Thank you kindly for helping again.  Sorry I was caught up with some other project work so I am slow on this.  But this helps me tremendously. It worked.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

An expansion on my comment:

```bat
@Echo Off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "FILENAME.EXT=%~1"
For /F "Delims=" %%X in ("!FILENAME.EXT!") Do for %%F in ("%%~nX") Do (Set "_DT=%%~xF" & Set "_FN=%%~nF.!_DT:~1,8!")
Echo/!_FN!
Endlocal & Exit /B
```

**Note:** the above is not scripted to your exact usage situation, it only demonstrates the principle in a testable way for you to be able to adapt to your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, I will try and will let you know if it works.

Comment: It worked.  Thank you so much for the suggestion.  It worked.