# Get Newest File Among Many then Rename the Newest File Name Keeping First 33 Characters

Tags: timestamp, filenames, batch-rename

This is exactly what I had:  In one folder, there can be many files with same names but different dates:  
AAAAAAA.BBB.CCC_DDD.EEEE.20200908*123945*  
AAAAAAA.BBB.CCC_DDD.EEEE.20200827*14411*

I need to get only the newest file to SFTP it to another server.  
The newest file needs to be renamed and removed the last part of file name.  I should have date stamp only, no time stamp.  That meant, keeping only the first 33 characters.  The desired result is:  
**AAAAAAA.BBB.CCC_DDD.EEEE.20200908**

Would you please help? I can confirm that 1/. the time stamps are different: longer or shorter.  That was not under my control.  2/. the files had no extension.  the file names look exactly like I described above.

I have tried these script however it did not work:

```
FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR c:\test\AAAAAAA.BBB.CCC_DDD* /B /O:D') DO SET NEWEST_FILE=%%I  <br/>
echo "Newest Filename = %NEWEST_FILE%"  <br/>
ren "%NEWEST_FILE%" "?????????????????????????????????"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch job remove timestamp in a filename with date and time stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63308625/batch-job-remove-timestamp-in-a-filename-with-date-and-time-stamp)

Answer (score 0):

@Compo, thank you very much for helping me.  Thanks to you, it worked.  And this is what I did:

```
@Echo Off   
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion 
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Dir /B /A:-D "<.<.<.>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"') Do (
    Set "DateStamp=%%~xG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Ren "%%G" "%%~nG!DateStamp:~,9!"
    EndLocal
)
FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR c:\test\AAAAAAA.BBB.CCC_DDD.EEEE* /B /O:D') DO SET NEWEST_FILE=%%I   
echo %NEWEST_FILE%
```